# Can a F-value in a two-way ANOVA go as high as $F>150$?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I have a two-factor experimental design with 2*4 ANOVA. The F-value I am getting is very much above the critical value ($F=166.51$).

My first guess is that it might be because of large sample size($n=360$), but am I right to assume so? Can the F-value be as big as that? Or might it be due to some error (which I have checked for again and again)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly F can be that high.  Of course, you need to make sure you've got the right data and so on, but if that's the case, then it just indicates that your model is accounting for nearly all the variation in the data. Often, this is a sign that what you are testing for is obvious.

Suppose, for example, you tried to predict a person's height from the height of their mother and their father.  F would be huge because those two factors are very important in predicting height.

Answer (score 1):

Even at smaller sample sizes F values can be substantially larger than that.

Of itself it doesn't suggest an error.

Comment: $F$-value doesn't really depend on the sample size at all, does it? The $p$-value of course does, but not the $F$.

Comment: @amoeba Not really\*; I mentioned sample size because it was raised in the question. $\quad$ \* well, *sort of*.